# Why python raises exception on udp recvfrom

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, sockets, udp

I have realy simple python27 script on Windows10

It is just sends messages and waits for reply using udp socket

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1" 
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

print "UDP target IP:", UDP_IP
print "UDP target port:", UDP_PORT
print "message:", MESSAGE

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
sock.recvfrom(1200)
```

On Windows 10 it raises exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "simple.py", line 14, in <module>
print sock.recv(1200)
socket.error: [Errno 10054]
```

On Linux it works fine.

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Socket error 10054 is a connection reset. This happens on other ports too? Try to use sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

Comment: same story. nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here [Windows UDP sockets: recvfrom() fails with error 10054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242622/windows-udp-sockets-recvfrom-fails-with-error-10054) Author made the same. He ignores this error. But maybe it is true way of solving this problem.
I just put `recvfrom` in `while` and wrapped it with `try..except`
And I ignore any errors. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The first several lines of your program are opening a socket to send data which all is fine. But the sock.recvfrom line doesn't have an associated bind with it.

In other words, when you send on UDP you shouldn't expect to receive anything back. If you want to send a message and then wait for a reply (which will not be automatic from a remote system) you need to bind the socket to a listening port.

This site: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication has some great references.

Comment: First of all it works on Linux. Second - i added bind but it is still gives me the same error. I dont want something back. Maybe i want just recive data from anywhere. I found solution but it is ugly http://pastebin.com/rXR3Pke9. This error raises on first recvfrom. On other steps it is works. I just put recvfrom in `while` and wrapped it with `try..except`.

Comment: I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242622/windows-udp-sockets-recvfrom-fails-with-error-10054   Author made the same. He ignores this error. But maybe it is true way of solving this problem