# recv() doesn't give SOCKET_ERROR when ICMP port unreachable comes

Tags: c, windows, udp, winsock, icmp

##### Platform

Winows 11

##### What I want to do

I'm writing a UDP ping tool by using [rfc1122 - 3.2.2.1 Destination Unreachable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122), which is the same method as traceroute UDP mode on Linux. Here is the procedure:

1. Send UDP packet to target host
2. The target host recv the UDP packet (but on a non-service port)
3. The target host send a ICMP port unreachable packet back (type 3, code 3)
4. Recv ICMP port unreachable packet from target host

##### Problem

According to [Microsoft document - recv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv#return-value), `recv()` should return `SOCKET_ERROR` when getting the ICMP port unreachable, but it doesn't.

##### Checks

ICMP packet actually comes. (by WireShark)

##### Pseudo Code

```c
int main(void)
{
    SOCKET sk;
    struct sockaddr_in dst_sockaddr;
    char buf[1280];
    int ret;

    /* specified the destination */
    dst_sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dst_sockaddr.sin_port = MY_DST_PORT;  // a non-service port
    dst_sockaddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = MY_DST_IP;

    /* create socket */
    sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    connect(sk, (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));  // for using recv()

    /* send */
    send(sk, "hello", 5, 0);

    /* recv */
    ret = recv(sk, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);  // Blocked here!!
    printf("recv() returns %d\n", ret);

    closesocket(sk);
    return 0;
}
```

##### Similar Issues from Others

1. [x/net/icmp: listen icmp in Windows not work properly](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38427)
   Not for UDP socket, it's for raw socket.
2. [Windows UDP sockets: recvfrom() fails with error 10054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242622/windows-udp-sockets-recvfrom-fails-with-error-10054/42409198#42409198)
   The command `SIO_UDP_CONNRESET` is for Windows XP. ([ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-ioctls#sio_udp_connreset-opcode-setting-i-t3))

##### Questions

I want to get `SOCKET_ERROR` if I get a ICMP port unreachable packet. Is there any details I miss? Or some socket options, IO controls I need to enable? Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason (in my case):
ICMP unreachable packets blocked by firewall (even WireShark captures it).

Solution to this case:
Add allow inbound ICMPv4 (type3, code3) and ICMPv6 (type1, code4) traffic (for all apps) to firewall whitelist. (Specified an app isn't effective)

References:
[WireShark: Ethernet capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet)
[Can firewall block packets visible in Wireshark?](https://serverfault.com/questions/624952/can-firewall-block-packets-visible-in-wireshark)